# Get the loaded Image from Image Control using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

I have a problem with retrieving the image shown in my WPF Image Control

```
<Image x:Name="img" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Source="{Binding ImageSource, Source={x:Static vm:ItemProvider.instance}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="{Binding ElementName=ScrollBar, Path=Value}" />
                                            </Image.RenderTransform>

                                        </Image>
```

I rotate the Image using `Scrollbar`

And i want to retrieve it as shown in the control

this is how i load image to the Image Control

```
        private byte[] _ImageSource;
        public byte[] ImageSource
        {
            get { return _ImageSource; }
            set
            {
                _ImageSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
            }
        }
```

I am trying to retrieve the image shown in the Image Control by getting the `ImageSource` but they are not the same. I rotate the Image 90 degrees. But the return Image is the same when i load it.

but using code behind i can access the image like this

`img.Source` then i convert the source into byte array

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ImageSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating the Image element does in no way rotate the ImageSource in its Source property.

To create a rotated ImageSource, use a [`TransformedBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.transformedbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var sourceBitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(ImageSource))
{
    sourceBitmap.BeginInit();
    sourceBitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    sourceBitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    sourceBitmap.EndInit();
}

// This should be another view model property that the Slider is bound to.
// Only multiples of 90 degrees are valid values.
var rotationAngle = 90d;

var rotation = new RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

var rotatedBitmap = new TransformedBitmap(sourceBitmap, rotation);
```

---

To avoid that you have to create a new source bitmap for every conversion, your should change the type of your ImageSource property from `byte[]` to `ImageSource`.

In order to write this back into another `byte[]`, use one of the `BitmapEncoder` classes, e.g. `PngBitapEncoder`.

Comment: Hi Clemens. But using the code the image can only be rotate in increments of 90 degrees. But i need any value from the slider up to 360. How can i solve it in my case? Or i use a  library like ImageMagick. But the pc of the users are slow.  Thank you.

Comment: I was under the impression tha you wanted to do exactly that, as you wrote "I rotate the Image 90 degrees". Anyway, you may alternatively  render the rotated Image element into a RenderTargetBitmap.

Comment: will it be alright for you to share some code. i can't make it work. I can't convert the RotateTransform into byte[] i tried searching the RenderTargetBitmap but the output is not what i expect.

Comment: "the output is not what i expect". so what do you expect? You should have an idea how exactly you want the result to look like when you rotate by anything else than multiples of 90°. The output bitmap is rectangular, so you either cut parts off or leave parts empty.